# Why isn't this solution working? Find common characters using two Maps

Tags: javascript, dictionary

This is a problem from leetcode. The problem description is

> Given an array A of strings made only from lowercase letters, return a list of all characters that show up in all strings within the list (including duplicates).  For example, if a character occurs 3 times in all strings but not 4 times, you need to include that character three times in the final answer.

I tried to implement a solution using two maps but it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
var commonChars = function(A) {
    let resultMap = new Map();
    let map = new Map();
    let result = [];

    var fillmap = function(map, string){
        for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
            if(map.has(string[i])){
                map.set(string[i], map.get(string[i])+1);
            }else{
                map.set(string[i], 1);
            }
        }
    };

    fillmap(resultMap, A[0]);


    for(let j=1; j<A.length; j++){
        fillmap(map, A[j]);
        for(var key in resultMap){
            if(!map.has(key)){
                resultMap.delete(key);
            }else if(map.get(key) < resultMap.get(key)){
                resultMap.set(key, map.get(key));
            }
        }
        map.clear();
    }

    for(var key in resultMap){
        for(let k=0; k<resultMap.get(key); k++){
            result.push(key);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

The test case is an array: ["bella", "label", "roller"], the actual output is a blank array but the expected output is ["e", "l", "l"]

Answer (score 1):

A Map has no keys (in the sense that it is an object, like everything in JS, and as an object, it has no keys (it inherits `.size` and others though). To get the keys of a Map, use `.keys()`. So this (among others):

```
 for(var key in resultMap)
```

has to be:

```
 for(let key of resultMap.keys())
```

---

I'd do (yes, I could not resist the challenge - stop reading if you haven't solved it on your own!):

> ```
> const commonChars = input => input.reduce(
>   (dupes, str) => str.split("").filter(c => dupes.includes(c) && dupes.splice(dupes.indexOf(c), 1)), 
>   input[0].split("")
> );
> ```